# How do i join pivot tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, pivot-table

I need help

I have this 2 tables

Tab1

```
 ID     Food 
 1      Chcicken  
 2      Pork
```

and Tab2

```
 Customers  Food  Cost   
  1          1     45
  1          2     12
  2          2     12
```

How do I make it look like this?

```
Customers   Chicken   Pork
 1            45       12
 2           NULL      12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR( MAX ),
        @query AS NVARCHAR( MAX )
SELECT @cols = STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME( Food )
                        FROM Tab1
                        FOR XML PATH( '' ),
                        TYPE
                      ).value( '.', 'NVARCHAR( MAX )' ),
                      1,
                      1,
                      ''
                    )
SET @query = 'SELECT Customers, ' + @cols +
             'FROM ( SELECT Customers,
                            Tab1.Food AS FoodName,
                            Cost
                     FROM Tab1
                     LEFT JOIN Tab2 On Tab2.Food = Tab1.ID
                   ) AS prePivot
              PIVOT
              (
                  SUM( Cost )
                  FOR FoodName IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) p'
EXECUTE( @query );
```

This code starts with the declaration of two variables...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR( MAX ),
        @query AS NVARCHAR( MAX )
```

The next segment will generate a string such as `[Chicken], [Pork]`, but with whatever values of `Food` happen to be in `Tab1` when the code is run...

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME( Food )
                        FROM Tab1
                        FOR XML PATH( '' ),
                        TYPE
                      ).value( '.', 'NVARCHAR( MAX )' ),
                      1,
                      1,
                      ''
                    )
```

The value of `@cols` is then used to construct a string (assigned to `@query`) which contains a statement such as the following...

```
SELECT Customers, [Chicken], [Pork]
FROM ( SELECT Customers,
              Tab1.Food AS FoodName,
              Cost
       FROM Tab1
       LEFT JOIN Tab2 On Tab2.Food = Tab1.ID
     ) AS prePivot
PIVOT
(
    SUM( Cost )
    FOR FoodName IN ([Chicken], [Pork])
) p
```

The subquery `prePivot` generates a joined dataset such as...

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| Tab1.ID | Tab1.Name | Tab2.Customers | Tab2.Food | Tab2.Cost |
+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1       | Chicken   | 1              | 1         | 45        |
| 2       | Pork      | 1              | 2         | 12        |
| 2       | Pork      | 2              | 2         | 12        |
+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

It selects from the joined dataset the following fields and their data...

```
+-----------+----------+------+
| Customers | FoodName | Cost |
+-----------+----------+------+
| 1         | Chicken  | 45   |
| 1         | Chicken  | 12   |
| 2         | Pork     | 12   |
+-----------+----------+------+
```

Please note that I gave `Tab1.Food` the alias `FoodName` as `PIVOT` does not seem to get on well with joined datasets that have repeated field names (such as with `Food`).  Giving `Tab1.Food` an alias of `Food` also seems to generate trouble.

The pivot then populates the generated fields `Chicken` and `Pork` with the pivoted data.  Please note that an aggregate function (such as `SUM()`) *must* be used, which also has the effect of grouping by the unpivoted field(s) (in this case, just `Customers`).

Also please note that where the pivot does not find a source value corresponding to a value that it is generating, then it uses `NULL` instead.

The nonpivoted fields from the outer `SELECT` are populated with their grouped values.

**Appendix**

I tested my code against a databse created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE Tab1
(
    ID     INT,
    Food   VARCHAR( 10 )
);
INSERT INTO Tab1 ( ID,
                   Food
                 )
VALUES ( 1, 'Chicken' ),
       ( 2, 'Pork' );
CREATE TABLE Tab2
(
    Customers   INT,
    Food        INT,
    Cost        INT
);
INSERT INTO Tab2 ( Customers,
                   Food,
                   Cost
                 )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 45 ),
       ( 1, 2, 12 ),
       ( 2, 2, 12 );
```

The desired output was achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Joining first to get the `name` of the food and then using `pivot` on the result set would work for you:

```
;with tab1
as
(
    select 1 as id, 'chicken' as food
    union all
    select 2 as id, 'pork' as food
),

tab2 as 
(
    select 1 as customer, 1 as food, 45 as cost
    union all
    select 1 as customer, 2 as food, 12 as cost
    union all
    select 2 as customer, 2 as food, 12 as cost
)
select *
from
(
  select t2.customer, t1.food, t2.cost as cost
  from tab1 t1 join tab2 t2 on t1.id = t2.food
) r
pivot (max(cost) for food in ([chicken], [pork])) t
```

Please note that the `CTEs` here are only used as source tables `tab1` and `tab2` to recreate your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select * from tab1 t left outer join 
  tab2 t2 on t.id=t2.food

  select * from
  (select t2.Customers,t.Food,t2.cost from tab1 t left outer join 
  tab2 t2 on t.id=t2.food
  ) AS sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(cost)
    FOR food IN ([Chcicken],[Pork])
) AS pvt
```